# How to perform a calculation based on a newly created value at a previous index?

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement

I have a dataset with two columns. One column is dates and the second is a multiple metric. I want to create a third column (New_Col) that looks at the current multiple and the previously created value and multiply them. So the first one would

```
Date           Multiple   
01-01-2020        1          
01-01-2020        1         
01-01-2020        3          
01-01-2020        1          
01-01-2020        1          
01-01-2020        1          
01-01-2020        4          
01-01-2020        1
```

Function:

```
def new_func(df):
```

**Output**

```
Date           Multiple   New_Col
01-01-2020        1          1
01-01-2020        1          1
01-01-2020        3          3
01-01-2020        1          3
01-01-2020        1          3
01-01-2020        1          3
01-01-2020        4          12
01-01-2020        1          12
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are trying to create the value of a column based upon its previous value.

  - Vectorized operations compute values based upon existing values and then update the column values all at once, so there's not a way to access the newly created, previous value.
  - In order to perform a calculation based upon the previous value, you must have access to the previous value while performing the calculation for the current value

    - This can be done by assigning each value to a list and then access the value at the previous index
- See [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) for usage details.
- The following implementation works while the dataframe index is `range(0, len(df)-1)`, unique ordered integers beginning with 0.

  - Because `df` index `i` is being used to address `new_col`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-01-2020', '01-01-2020'],
        'Multiple': [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# function to perform multiplication
def create_new_column(dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> list:
    new_col = list()
    for i, (d, m) in df.iterrows():  # i is the current index location; based on the shape of the example dataframe
        if i == 0:
            new_col.append(m * 1)
        else:
            new_col.append(m * new_col[i-1])  # [i-1] previous index location
    return new_col


# call function and create new_col
df['new_col'] = create_new_column(df)

# display(df)
         Date  Multiple  new_col
0  01-01-2020         1        1
1  01-01-2020         1        1
2  01-01-2020         3        3
3  01-01-2020         1        3
4  01-01-2020         1        3
5  01-01-2020         1        3
6  01-01-2020         4       12
7  01-01-2020         1       12
```